# Delta for file upload

Tags: dropbox-api

I would like to synchronize uploads from our own server to our clients' dropboxes to which we have full access. syncing changes on dropbox is easy because i can use the delta call, but I need a more efficient way to identify and upload changes made locally to dropbox.

The sync api would be amazing for this but I'm not trying to make a mobile app so the languages with the api are not easily accessible (AFAIK). Is there an equivalent to the sync api for python running on a linux server?

Possible solution:

So far, I was thinking of using anydbm to store string,string dictionaries that would hold folder names as the key and the hash generated from the metadata call from the server. then I could query the dropbox and every time I run into a folder, I will check the folder compared with the metadata on the anydbm.

if there is a difference, compare the file dates/sizes in the folder and if there are any subfolders, recurse the function into them,

if it the same, skip the folder.

This should save a substantial amount of time compared to the current verification of each and every file, but if there are better solutions, please do let me know.

Comment: See also https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=110967 on the Dropbox API forum.

Comment: thanks for cross linking it. If I find the solution on Dropbox's forum I will post it here and vice versa.